# adding Junit setup/@Before logic without changing code?

Tags: java, ant, junit

Can I add code to be run before each test case/suite by configuration, without changing code? 
Is there a way to add setup logic for a large suite of tests in one place rather than many files?

Use case: Hundreds of Junit tests are currently failing. A solution would be simply run a piece of code before all of them (or at least as many times as JVM started), to do some singleton init. I want to avoid changing hundreds of files right now, just somehow ask Junit to execute a given init class/method. (Reason: 1) minimize duplication 2) we're in sort of a code freeze - no commits to repo would be preferred)

I guess I could extend the TestRunner class, and do the init there - but maybe there is a nicer way. BTW, the suite is run via Ant, and I can't see a way to pass in my own testrunner either.

Comment: Extending the test runner is probably not the _nicest_ way, but it's probably the easiest. You'd ideally want to have the `@BeforeClass` annotation on a method in each of your tests, but as you've said, changing hundreds of files may make this a less attractive option.

Comment: What about good old "search-and-replace"? With some clever regexp you could probably insert the setup method into all of your test cases.

Comment: Thanks @RyanJ - any idea on how to use a custom test runner from an ant script?

Comment: @isnot2bad - yes I could automate adding boilerplate code using regexes ..  but I'd want to avoid it, especially that we're in a code freeze.. (Q updated)

Comment: Given the situation you are in, you could experiment with "org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitResultFormatter "  . The name is formatter, but you could listen for events such as suite started, test started and perform some common stuff(what ever you have in mind). Docs  at http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused since you say you don't want to change the code but seem OK writing a custom test runner.  Wouldn't that mean changing the test code?

If you can change the test code but not the source code, the easiest way around this problem is to add init methods to your test suite classes (if you have them) and annotating them with `@BeforeClass`

```
public class MySuite{

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initSingleton(){
            //...
    }
}
```

This method will run once before any of the test classes in the suite are run so you shouldn't have much code duplication and can even maybe add this to the root suite if you always run all the tests.

Comment: Thanks. No test suite classes yet - would I not have to list all (relevant) Tests in one of them?  By "code" change I mean a commit to the source/test in the repository (any new commit triggers a big CI pipeline with a chain of events I want to avoid). Tools(eg junit runner) change  with only rerunning tests would be ok.